# UIButton setImage not updating in Reusable TableView Cell for Localization image name strings

Tags: ios, localization, uibutton

There are couple of Reusable Cells contain UIButtons in the table view. Every UIButton has two images for two status. 
In order to achieve localization, in the UITableViewCell -> initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder, I have written following lines for localizing image name.

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"buttonStateSelected", @"")] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"buttonStateNormal", @"")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setNeedsDisplay];


[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"buttonStateSelected", @"")] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"buttonStateNormal", @"")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setNeedsDisplay];
```

I can see the image names are localized by NSLocalizedString(), but on the simulator and iOS device, the button has no change.

I have tried other similar questions' answers, none of them is working.
I have tried [button setImage:forState:], it doesn't work.
I did setNeedsDisplay, no hope.
I even give some wrong image names, the button still is the original storyboard image.

Why I can't change button's image and backgroundImage real-time? Is there any solution?

Comment: I noticed you are always referring to the state state: UIControlStateSelected.  Should you be referring to UIControlStateNormal for the second line of each section of code you provided?

Comment: It is my question edit error. It is not apear in the source code.

Comment: What is `self.button` ? Doesn't look like the one in cell

Comment: @MidhunMP this code is in the TableViewCell, not the Table View Controller. the self means the cell [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

Comment: @RobertYiJiang: Check whether `[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"buttonStateSelected", @"")]` these returns a valid UIImage or not

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes, it does right thing. It can returns the right localized string like "xxx-italian.png". But the button looks like ignored my image setting.

Comment: @RobertYiJiang: I mean to check whether that code returns an UIImage or not. (I know that localization will return a string you defined, I'm asking whether the code returns a UIImage or not). Probably image will be nil.

Comment: @MidhunMP I just tested the code. The image is right. It is Italian button image. But the button still is English one.

Comment: @RobertYiJiang: Can you check self.button is nil or not ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Thank you soooo much!! It is nil. But, when and where the customized table view cell will initial button?

Comment: @RobertYiJiang: Is that a outlet connected ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes, it is connected. the problem is I invoke setImage too early, in the - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{}. I just moved it into - (void)awakeFromNib{}, and It solved the problem. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @MidhunMP Can you answer this question? I will accept your answer. Thank you!